# Ask some inserted row not trigger the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making some function in this

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kunyuki/sqatzre4/)

```
 var counter = 2;
$("#add").click(function () {

var newTextBoxTr = $(document.createElement('tr'))
     .attr("id", 'pilihan' + counter);  
newTextBoxTr.after().html('<td>pilihan</td><td>text</td><td><a name="add">test</a></td>');
newTextBoxTr.insertAfter("#pilihan"+(counter-1)); 
counter++;
 });

$("a[name='add']").click(function () {
var newTextBoxTr = $(document.createElement('tr'))
     .attr("id", 'pilihan' + counter);  
newTextBoxTr.after().html('<td>pilihan</td><td>text</td><td><a id="add" name="add">test</a></td>');
newTextBoxTr.insertAfter("#pilihan"+(counter-1)); 
counter++;
 });
```

another tag a that have name="add" or id="add" on some inserted row not executing the function click. help me

Comment: you cannot hace more than one id ='add' it will not work naturally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** method, since some of them were created dynamically

```js
var counter = 2;
$('#table').on('click', "#add,a[name='add']", function() {

  var newTextBoxTr = $(document.createElement('tr'))
    .attr("id", 'pilihan' + counter);
  newTextBoxTr.after().html('<td>pilihan</td><td>text</td><td><a name="add">test</a></td>');
  newTextBoxTr.insertAfter("#pilihan" + (counter - 1));
  counter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border=1 width=1000>
    <tr id="pilihan1">
        <td>Pilihan polling</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td id="bpilihan1"><a id="add" name="add">test</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
        <td>
<a id="add" name="add">test</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: its work but, how to make the "<a name='add'>test</a>" dissapear after click ?

Comment: @HilmiAl-asAri  : which `<a name='add'>test</a>` , do you mean the clicked tag,  then use `$(this).remove()`

Comment: no, i mean replace the tag with <label>added</label>

Comment: then use `$(this).html('added')` or `$(this).text('added')`